# Streaming songs to connected devices using gamekit

Tags: iphone, gamekit

I want to play the song from one iphone to the other, it is like the user from device A selects a song from his IPod and plays it, while the users on Device B can also listen to that song using their own iphone which is connected to the Device A using either the Game Kit or wifi. 
So is it possible to stream the song from the ipod library to the other devices or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible technically, because you can't get to the audio data -- either as a decoded PCM stream or as the original encoded AAC or MP3 files -- via the `MPMusicPlayerController` or any other public API. Therefore device A is not in a position to send audio data over the network to device B.

Device B could receive and play streamed audio from the network, of course, since that's what apps like Pandora, Last.fm, and AOL Radio do.  But for device A to send the data, it would have to use some source other than its own iPod library.

Comment: Can you not capture any/all audio output? ipod library or otherwise?

Comment: It's a little less impossible in iOS 4 and up. It's now possible to get the MPMeidaPropertyAssetURL for an audio item in the library, and open it with AV Foundation. You could use the AVAssetReader to read from the file and then stream them over the GameKit connection.  But this is all about reading from the song in the library... there's still no way to capture system audio, like the audio being produced by other (background) applications.

Comment: Do you know how to send music data in a STREAMING fashion over GameKit?

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of copyright protection, I don't think this is possible - legally, that is.

It might be possible technically, in that you may be able to send the raw bytes of the song file over wifi or bluetooth and then decode and play them on the second device, but that surely won't get past Apple's reviewers.