# Stream audio from iPhone to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm really a newbie at iPhone development, but some friend of mine asked me something and I can't figure out the right answer:

Can you stream audio from to devices with an app? For instance, both devices open the app, the master device starts playing some song, but the sound goes out on the slave device? Is this doable?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this, should give you the answer. In short: NO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221073/streaming-songs-to-connected-devices-using-gamekit .

Comment: LordT is right, good link. Also, from a legal standpoint, it wouldn't make it. Apple wouldn't allow it

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be feasible with AirPlay since [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/airview/id412370918?mt=8) turns your iPhone into an AirPlay device (just like the Apple TV). However, I think they had to reverse engineer the AirPlay protocol in order to make this app.  Also, it is unclear whether it will stay on the App Store for a very long time.